# Strange scenario involving mail merge

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a complicated task I need to perform for my employer involving mail merge. We have an excel spreadsheet that has the following columns: last name, first name, email, attended (just an X for attended, blank for did not attend). We have a couple spreadsheets set up this same way each with about 350-400 rows. The email address field is the email address of the person's supervisor, so we have several people that have the same email address listed.

What I'm supposed to do is create certificates for every person that attended on the spreadsheet. I know how to do this with mail merge, but it's how they want me to organize it that is strange. They want a folder created for every email address and the certificates that belong with that address in that folder. Each certificate can either be its own document or they can all be pages in one document for that email address.

Does anyone have any idea as to what the best approach to this problem would be? I know how to create the mail merge from the excel spreadsheet I just don't know how to easily create all the folders and separate the certificates.

Comment: Python (http://www.python.org) would be able to do this.

Comment: @user-something: so would many, many other languages. Excel-VBA, for instance.

Comment: Please clarify your question by e.g. making it shorter and to the point, and avoiding editorializing. Are you just looking for a way to make folders from VBA? I've read this 3 times and still not sure what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the email address part it seems you need some file/folder handling. Just have a look at the [FSO (File System Object)](http://www.techbookreport.com/tutorials/fso1.html) in VBA.

If you have a list of the mail adresses you simply need to create a folder for each one and place the certificates there.

Comment: Full FSO documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28v=VS.85%29.aspx